How do I make dropdown selections add value to a totals column in Google Sheets
Very new to Google sheets and very lost.
I am trying to create an awards tracker for school Merits 2024
Ideally, I want to include drop down menus with options for each week we hand out merits at school e.g. Week 1, Week 2 etc. Depending on the week, these awards are worth either 5 or 10 points. (Wk 4 and 7 are 10 points, all other weeks are 5 points.)
My aim is to then have a total column that keeps track of how many points students should have (Column B in example.) E.g. If I get a merit in Week 4, then 10 points gets added to the total in column B.
I have also added conditional formatting to this column so that depending on the points, I know what level they are on e.g. bronze, silver and gold.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

One way is to use map() and ifs(), like this:
=sum(map(D2:2, lambda(week, ifs( 
  week = "N/A", 0, 
  week = "", 0, 
  week = "Week 4", 10, 
  week = "Week 7", 10, 
  true, 5    
))))

See map() and ifs().

Thank you! That worked!

Thanks. Yes and I am very lost haha

Using REGEXMATCH
# SYNTAX 
=REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression)
Single Row Formula
Needs to be copied down for each row.
=INDEX(
   SUM( REGEXMATCH(D2:E2, "4|7") * 10,
        REGEXMATCH(D2:E2, "[^47\D]") * 5)) 

Multi-Row Formula
BYROW is added so a single LAMBDA's formula can return the results for all rows that have a student listed.
=BYROW( FILTER(D2:E, A2:A<>""), LAMBDA(r,
     INDEX(
       SUM( REGEXMATCH(r, "4|7") * 10,
            REGEXMATCH(r, "[^47\D]") * 5))

Explanation
Regular Expressions

REGEXMATCH is used within INDEX to return TRUE/FALSE values for the range (row) rather than just one cell:
# Single Cell Version 
=REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "4|7")=TRUE
=REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "[^47\D]")=FALSE 

# INDEX (Array) Version 
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "4|7"))={TRUE, FALSE}
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "[^47\D]"))={FALSE, TRUE}

Sheets will coerce TRUE & FALSE to 1 & 0 if used in a calculation that requires digits. This behavior is leveraged to multiply the resulting array of matches for 4 or 7 by 10 and the other matched numbers by 5:
# TRUE & FALSE to 1 & 0 
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "4|7")*10)
=INDEX({TRUE, FALSE}*10)
={1*10, 0*10}
={10, 0} 

=INDEX(REGEXMATCH({"Week 7", "Week 2"}, "[^47\D]") * 5)
=INDEX({FALSE, TRUE} * 5)
={0*5, 1  *5}
={0, 5}

All that remains is to SUM the two arrays to get the total.
# Where range={"Week 7", "Week 2"} 
=INDEX(SUM(REGEXMATCH(range, "4|7") *10), REGEXMATCH(range, "[^47\D]") *5)
=INDEX(SUM({TRUE, FALSE}*10, {FALSE, TRUE} * 5))
=INDEX(SUM({10, 0},{0, 5}))
=15


